# trying to Dockerize a Django/Pyhton project, with no success

Tags: django, docker

I'm trying to dockerize a backend project, made with django/python and postgreSQL

It works as an API, The structure is:

```
backend
   api
      models.py
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
   menu_back
      manage.py
      settings.py
   Dockerfile
   requirements.txt
```

But I get an error saying that moule backend can't be found

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python 3.11.2 runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.11.2

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app/backend

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install the Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the Django project code into the container
COPY . .

# Set environment variables for PostgreSQL
ENV POSTGRESHOST=db
ENV POSTGRESPORT=5432
ENV POSTGRESUSER=postgres
ENV POSTGRESPASSWORD=mypassword
ENV POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase

CMD python menu_back/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

# Expose the port on which the Django server will run
EXPOSE 8000
```

I move to the backend directory and execute 'docker build -t backend-image -f Dockerfile .'

it runs ok, but when trying to run it with 'docker run -p 8000:8000 backend-image', I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

In the file manage.py, I have

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.menu_back.settings")
```

I don't know how to fix it, even ChatGPT is cycling with answers but the same all the time

Please, if somebody know the answer, I appreciate it

Rafael

I tried using ChatGPT, But I don't know how to fix the error

Comment: Can you post the whole tracelog of error? You could not overwrite every name of `backend` project, generally when you place Django application in seperate directories there are a few things to change. ChatGPT will not help with it either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like with

```py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.menu_back.settings")
```

the `manage.py` file in the folder `menu_back` is trying to access the settings with the relative path `backend.menu_back.settings` but there is no `backend` folder in `menu_back`.

The solution should be to move the `manage.py` file in the root of your Django project in the `backend` folder, and change the settings path to :

```py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "menu_back.settings")
```

It is also an usually good practice to put the `manage.py` file at the root of your Django project, as it is easier to access all the management commands.